# maxFiles not work in react-admin - dropZone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin, dropzone, react-dropzone

I have tried to put a file limit to the ImageInput of react-admin built with react-dropzone, in two ways, the first is to pass the ** maxFiles ** as a property directly:

```
<ImageInput
    className={classes.dropZone}
    source="images"
    label=""
    accept="image/*"
    multiple
    maxSize={1000000}
    maxFiles={2}
    placeholder={
        <p>Cargar imagen/es<br/><br/><br/>
            <span >
              *El archivo no debe exceder 1MB de tamaño
            </span>
        </p>
      }>
    <ImageField source="src" title="title"/>
</ImageInput>
```

and the second is to pass it through the ** options ** which does not work either.

```
<ImageInput
    className={classes.dropZone}
    source="images"
    label=""
    accept="image/*"
    multiple
    maxSize={1000000}
    options={{ maxFiles:2 }}
    placeholder={
        <p>Cargar imagen/es<br/><br/><br/>
            <span >
              *El archivo no debe exceder 1MB de tamaño
            </span>
        </p>
      }>
    <ImageField source="src" title="title"/>
</ImageInput>
```

Anyone have any idea how I can fix it? or some other way to limit the amount of files that can be uploaded?

thank you very much

Comment: What version of react-dropzone are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the validate prop for workaround.

```
const maxFiles = () => (
    value => value && value.length > 10 ? "Max number of files exceeded" : undefined;

<ImageInput
    className={classes.dropZone}
    source="images"
    label=""
    accept="image/*"
    multiple
    maxSize={1000000}
    validate={maxFiles()}
    placeholder={
        <p>Cargar imagen/es<br/><br/><br/>
            <span >
              *El archivo no debe exceder 1MB de tamaño
            </span>
        </p>
      }>
    <ImageField source="src" title="title"/>
</ImageInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the old version of `react-dropzone`.

The most easy solution is to update the version.(The latest version is [11.3.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropzone))

If you want to do the same with the version, you can try to manage that manually like this using `onDrop` props.

```
onDrop={acceptedFiles => {
    // do nothing if no files
    let handleDropImages;
    if (acceptedFiles.length === 0) {
         return;
    } else if(acceptedFiles.length > 5){ // here i am checking on the number of files
         return notify('maxImages'); // here i am using react toaster to get some notifications. don't need to use it 
    }else {
         // do what ever you want 
    }
}}
```

You can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/issues/636)

Comment: I tried both ways, adding onDrop in my code with the same version and updating the library, it still doesn't work for me, I must be doing something wrong. I clarify that I am using it within a custom react-admin form called FormWithRedirect.